# Granting user rights/privs in OSX

Tags: mac-osx, permissions

I have a normal user that I'd like to give the ability to install OS X updates, and Office updates.  Please tell me this is a right that I can enable in `/etc/authorization`, or somewhere else?  I don't want to make them an admin on the machine just for this.

Answer (score 2):

You could grant the user this privilege with `sudo`.  I am not aware of any way to delegate this authority with the GUI.

Your entry in `/etc/sudoers` (edit with `visudo`.)

```
username    localhost=softwareupdate --install --all
```

Then the user can run from a terminal:

```
sudo softwareupdate --install --all
```

For more information see: [`man softwareupdate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/10.6/man8/softwareupdate.8.html), [`man sudo`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/sudo.8.html).

Comment: Definitely a good option for `softwareupdate` and could be wrapped in an AppleScript for non-technical users, but I'd hope one wouldn't always run all updates. Also doesn't help with other third-party updaters.

Comment: If they're non-technical, they probably shouldn't be trusted to run updates. Also, 3rd-party updates is left to an exercise for the user. The meat of this answer is to grant privileges with `sudo`. As well as whether or not OP should run with `--all` or read the man page and tailor for their own environment. Available updates can be checked with `--list` and installed as required. The sudoers entry will need to be updated accordingly.

Comment: +1 for "If they're non-technical, they probably shouldn't be trusted to run updates."

Answer (score 0):

You must make them an Administrator for them to run Software Updates and install Applications outside of their home folder.